# Can I snap windows by using Super Key?

Tags: unity, windows-7, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to automatically resize 2 windows to take up half of the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5017/way-to-automatically-resize-2-windows-to-take-up-half-of-the-screen)

Can I snap windows to the left, right, maximize by doing Super+ArrowLeft, Super+ArrowRight, Super+ArrowUp ?
This is a feature in Windows 7 and is really useful. Wondering if there's a possibility to to this in Unity.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can do maximize and minimize with Window+up and window+down key.. Don't know about the other two..
Here is the steps:

1. If you have not install the compizconfig setting manager, then go to the software center and install it.
2. Once installed, open it from unity menu.
3. Search for general options.
4. Open that option and then go to the Keybinding tab.
5. Change the keybinding for the "unmaximize window" and "maximize window"
   checkout the below screen shots.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: What about left and right?

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve various window placements by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing a numpad number which corresponds to the place you want it. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad4</kbd> will tile your window to the left side of the screen, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad6</kbd> to the right side, and so on.

Ubuntu 12.04 is planned to include a simple <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> / <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> binding to achieve the same effect. However, if you can't wait or want to configure this behavior yourself, see the [*"Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?"*](https://askubuntu.com/q/34145/24694) question.